# why action_call is not working but action_dial is working good.....even though i use permission in manifest

Tags: android, android-layout

In action_call application crashes....but action_dial sets the number on the dialer...I also try this

```
    <permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED"
            android:protectionLevel="signature|privileged" />
```

Here is the code.....that says app has stopped working...

```
   Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

   callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
   callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+Uri.encode(phoneNum.trim())));
   try {
          startActivity(callIntent);
       }
    catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex)
       {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Here is the manifest file...

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                package="com.example.sajid.contactdemo">

                <application
                    android:allowBackup="true"
                    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:label="@string/app_name"
                    android:supportsRtl="true"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
                    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                        <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                        </intent-filter>
                    </activity>
                    <activity android:name=".DisplayActivity"></activity>
                </application>
                ***<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>***
            </manifest>
```

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/08/31/hey-where-did-my-permission-go.html

Comment: Can you post your logcat to see which error was thrown ?

Comment: In Android 6, the permission system has changed.

Comment: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial:

Comment: @Alexandre Martin ....Here is the logcat error... java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent

Comment: What are your min, max and targeted Api in build gradle file ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it

Comment: @Alexandre Martin.........minSdkVersion 15 .....targetSdkVersion 23

Comment: Ok. So you have to look at the new permission system as @Bob Malooga suggests. You target API 23 so permissions must not be granted in the Manifest but in the activity itself, also called "Requesting permission at runtime" : https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @Alexandre Martin......so what i need to change is API below 23?? can u suggest me?? please..

Comment: You must follow instructions in the link I sent to request for CALL permission correctly